# Cleansing external XML data before sending to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

I'm working with a number of XML feeds to retrieve data (from an external source). I will be retrieving the data, then sending this to my own MySQL database, so that I can then manipulate it how I wish.

I'm just hoping for some advice on best practice in terms of this process please. I'd like to make this as automated as possible, but I'm cautious of sending unvalidated XML data from an external source straight to my own database.

I will be putting in place a few standard validations to escape strings, etc, but should I be looking to 'cleanse' every piece of data (automatically) before committing to my own DB?

Should I perhaps validate each piece of data against it's own set of rules before it makes it's way to my database?

I hope that's clear enough. I'd love to hear some opinions if possible please.

Comment: I guess you're particularly interested in the difference between a well formed XML document and a valid one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you should worry about: 1 sql injection 2 cross-site scripting.

The first one is simple just use prepared statemants mysqli or PDO.

For corss-site scripting you can either choose to clean it before you put it in a database or when you retrieve it. Personnely i like to do the second one. just use the function htmlspecialchars() before you echo something and you should be safe.